# Getting FILEVERSION from Visual C++ Resource File

Tags: c++, visual-c++, versioning

Are there some preprocessor keywords to use to access the FILEVERSION defined in my .rc file at compile time?

I don't really want to add extra code to read the file information from the compiled product itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The preprocessor runs on the .RC file as well.  Define the shared data in a header that is included by both the .RC and your source code.

i.e., in foo.h:

```
#define MY_PRODUCT_NAME Foo
```

Then in the foo.rc:

```
#include "foo.h"

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
   // Many lines omitted
   VALUE "ProductName", MY_PRODUCT_NAME
```

Then in foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

cout << MY_PRODUCT_NAME;
```

Comment: Good idea, but in the RC file it has a string block of information which also has the version info (in a slightly different format). Any way to simply access the RC file values rather than re-defining them and keeping them in a common place?

Comment: None that I know of - rc.exe is independent of cl.exe.

Comment: When you change the dialog or whatever you are working with, new .rc file is generated and old one is overwritten. So this `#include "foo.h"` will not be there anymore. This is not good solution.

Comment: @LihO - I don't understand what you are talking about - Modifying a dialog will change the .rc file but have no impact on foo.h, and therefore result in no change on the version resource generated or the defines that are consumed by C++ file.

Comment: 1. Create new MFC app with one dialog. 2. Create new header `foo.h` with following body: `#ifndef __FOO_H__
#define __FOO_H__
#define MY_VERSION "1.1.0.0"
#endif` 3. Write `"#include ""foo.h""\r\n"` in textinclude so that this line is generated even if you change dialog 4. Change line with file version to `VALUE "FileVersion", MY_VERSION` 5. Build solution, see how great it works 6. Change dialog - put there ListBox or whatever 7. Rebuild solution and see how `VALUE "FileVersion", MY_VERSION` was rewritten into `VALUE "FileVersion", "1.1.0.0"` 8. If you change foo.h now, it won't affect .rc...

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this problem is simple and works well and is not obliterated by the resource editor.
1. Move the whole VS_VERSION_INFO section into your .RC2 file.
2. Replace all the version numbers and strings with values you #define in a new version.h file.
3. Add #include "version.h" to your .RC2 file.
Now you can also include version.h in other .CPP files and use the #define values in your code, for example to display the app's version resources in a dialog.

Comment: Microsoft suggests this solution too (though it's not very easy to google): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237870/en-us

Comment: @Steed Link is broken. Do you know the current one?

Comment: @JimFoye, well, this is not easy to google indeed. I've found a mirror: https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/237/Q237870/. The article is called "HOWTO: Increment Version Information After Each Build in VC++". Also in my search I've found a nice blog post about the issue: https://silviuardelean.ro/2011/01/09/flexible-changes-for-product-version-properties-visual-c-binaries/